# Why is 101 in the probability distribution function?

Tags: probability

It seems that I cannot find how they do this exercise. I don't understand how they obtain the probability.

[image]

Comment: if $X$ represents the number of copies sold, where $X$ has an equal probability of being any integer between $150$ and $250$ inclusive, then how many such integers are there?  $250 - 150 + 1 = 101$.  It's like saying if you choose a number between $4$ and $11$ at random, how many such choices are there?  $11 - 4 + 1 = 8$.

Comment: why putting  + 1?

Comment: As heropup says, you have a *uniform* **discrete** *distribution* over $[[\$150..\$250]]$.  So there are $250-150+1$ integers from 150 to 250, including both ends.  (Count to verify that there are $8$ integers between $4$ and $11$, these are $\{4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\}$.)